# MySql date form

Tags: mysql

I have a form where the user has to insert a date but the date will appear correctly into the database only in this format yyyy-mm-dd. In any other form it will show 0000-00-00.

How can I change that to dd-mm-yyyy?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in your insert query

```
insert into your_table (date_column)
values (STR_TO_DATE('14-08-2014','%d-%m-%Y'))
```